# Export Revit file for Fusion 360 3D Print

Tags: fusion360, autodesk

I have a 3D printer hooked up with Fusion 360. I have a 3D drawing in Revit. What format should I export to in order get from Revit to Fusion 360?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[In Revit](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Revit-AddIns/files/GUID-93AE8701-3958-43E9-8D95-0C1650B88061-htm.html)**

Use STL Exporter 2019 to customize and export your Revit model to an STL file.

1. Click Add-in tab -> STL Exporter panel -> STL Exporter.
2. On the General tab, specify your STL file options.
3. On the Categories tab, specify which element categories will export to the STL file.
4. Click Save to create the STL file.

**[In Fusion 360](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4zgLqG68E0)**

5. Click on a valid project then click the Upload button. Then, click the Select files button and navigate to the STL you wish to import.
   [image: upload button]
6. After selecting the STL file you want to convert, click the Upload button, this time the one in the lower-right corner of the file upload window. Then, the STL file you selected will be imported into Fusion 360. The process can take a few minutes.
   [image: browse and open]